# Show that every planar graph admits an orientation such that each vertex has at most 3 outgoing edges

Tags: graph-theory

An orientation of any graph G=(V,E) is defined as any graph G′=(V,E′) arising by replacing each edge {u,v} of E(G) by a directed edge either {u,v} or {v,u}. Show that every planar graph admits an orientation such that each vertex has at most 3 outgoing edges.

someone give me this question and I don't how to solve it. can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This directly follows from Kuratowski's theorem. We know a planar graph cannot contain a topological $K_5$ or a topological $K_{3,3}$. I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: @DanielP can you tell a bit more?